# How to change the border color of Material UI TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I can't seem to figure out how to change the outline color of an outlined variant `TextField`

I looked around GitHub issues and people seem to be pointing towards using the `TextField` "InputProps" Property but this seems to do nothing.

[image: This is the field]

Here is my code in its current state

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const styles = theme => ({
  field: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
    height: '30px !important'
  },
});

class _Field extends React.Component {
      render() {
          const { classes, fieldProps } = this.props;
             return (
                <TextField
                {...fieldProps}
                label={this.props.label || "<Un-labeled>"}
                InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} // stop from animating.
                inputProps={{ className: classes.fieldInput }}
                className={classes.field}
                margin="dense"
               variant="outlined"
            />
        );
    }
}

_Field.propTypes = {
    label: PropTypes.string,
    fieldProps: PropTypes.object,
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default withStyles(styles)(_Field);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can override all the class names injected by Material-UI thanks to the `classes` property.
Have a look at [overriding with classes](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes) section and the [implementation of the component](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui/src/Input/Input.js) for more detail.

and finally :

[The API documentation of the Input React component. Learn more about the properties and the CSS customization points.](https://material-ui.com/api/input)

Answer (score 110):

https://codesandbox.io/s/6rx8p

```html
<CssTextField
  label="Username"
  className="username"
  name="username"
  onChange={this.onChange}
  type="text"
  autoComplete="current-password"
  margin="normal"
  inputProps={{ style: { fontFamily: 'nunito', color: 'white' } }}
/>
```

```
//declare the const and add the material UI style
const CssTextField = withStyles({
  root: {
    '& label': {
      color: 'red',
    },
    '& label.Mui-focused': {
      color: 'white',
    },
    '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
      borderBottomColor: 'yellow',
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      '& fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'white',
      },
      '&:hover fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'white',
      },
      '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'yellow',
      },
    },
  },
})(TextField);
```

Comment: very helful thanks =)

Comment: Is your color attribute working?

Answer (score 67):

Take a look at this, I made a quick demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-ui-custom-outline-color

It changes the default border color and the label color of the Material-UI TextField but keeps the primary color when focused.

Also, take a look at this link, it gave me the "idea":

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13347

If you want to change the color when focused look at these examples from the documentation:

https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#customization

Answer (score 35):

In case anyone wants to do this with styled-components:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import {TextField} from "@material-ui/core";

const WhiteBorderTextField = styled(TextField)`
  & label.Mui-focused {
    color: white;
  }
  & .MuiOutlinedInput-root {
    &.Mui-focused fieldset {
      border-color: white;
    }
  }
`;
```

This took me WAY too long to figure out. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 28):

```
const styles = theme => ({
  notchedOutline: {
    borderWidth: "1px",
    borderColor: "yellow !important"
  }
});

 <TextField
              variant="outlined"
              rows="10"
              fullWidth
              InputProps={{
                classes: {
                  notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline
                }
              }}
              id="standard-textarea"
              label="Input Set"
              helperText="Enter an array with elemets seperated by , or enter a JSON object"
              placeholder="Placeholder"
              multiline
              value={"" + this.props.input}
              onChange={this.props.handleChangeValue("input")}
              className={classes.textField}
              margin="normal"
            />
```

[image]

Answer (score 28):

*(This answer was written for Material-UI **v4**, but I assume the general idea applies for **v5** as well.)*

The Problem with the Textfield border is that the color you want to set
has a lower [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the original style that Material-UI (MUI) sets.

E.g. MUI sets this class when focused:

```
.MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
    border-color: (some color);
}
```

which is more specific than a custom selector like:

```
.Component-cssNotchedOutline {
    border-color: #f0f;
}
```

#### Solution A *(not recommended)*

You can add the `!important` exception to the color, but this is ['bad practice'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStyles, TextField, WithStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
interface IProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {}

const styles = createStyles({
    notchedOutline: { borderColor: '#f0f !important' },
});

export const TryMuiA = withStyles(styles)((props: IProps) => {
    const { classes } = props;
    return ( <TextField variant={ 'outlined' } label={ 'my label' }
        InputProps={ {
            classes: {
                notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
            },
        } }
    /> );
});
```

#### Solution B *(recommended)*

The [official MUI example](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#customized-inputs) uses other ways to increase specificity.

**The 'trick' is** not to style the Element directly, like:

```
.someChildElement { border-color: #f0f }
```

but to add some extra selectors (more than MUI does*), e.g.:

```
.myRootElement.someExtra { border-color: #f0f }
```

or:

```
.myRootElement .someChildElement { border-color: #f0f }
```

*(*Actually it might be enough to use the same selectors as MUI does,
because if specificity of the selectors is the same,
then the 'later' ones are used. But in case of [SSR](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/server-rendering/), the order of the CSS rules might [change after rehydration](https://mui.com/system/styles/api/#serverstylesheets).)*

**Include the parent:** You might have noticed that setting `notchedOutline` *does* set the color for the un-focused element, but not for the focused.
That is because the MUI style includes the *parent* element of the input box (`.MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused`).
So you need to include the parent as well.

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const styles = {
    root: {                           // - The TextField-root
        border: 'solid 3px #0ff',     // - For demonstration: set the TextField-root border
        padding: '3px',               // - Make the border more distinguishable

        // (Note: space or no space after `&` matters. See SASS "parent selector".)
        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {  // - The Input-root, inside the TextField-root
            '& fieldset': {            // - The <fieldset> inside the Input-root
                borderColor: 'pink',   // - Set the Input border
            },
            '&:hover fieldset': {
                borderColor: 'yellow', // - Set the Input border when parent has :hover
            },
            '&.Mui-focused fieldset': { // - Set the Input border when parent is focused 
                borderColor: 'green',
            },
        },
    },
};

export const TryMui = withStyles(styles)(function(props) {
    const { classes } = props;
    return (<TextField label="my label" variant="outlined"
        classes={ classes }
    />);
})
```

**Note** that you can increase specificity in different ways, e.g. this would work as well (a bit different):

```
    '& fieldset.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
        borderColor: 'green',
    },
```

**Remark:** It might seem a little bit 'dirty' to add selectors only to increase specificity,
when you don't really 'need' them. I think it is, but this workaround was sometimes
the only solution since CSS was invented, so it is considered *kind of acceptable*.

Answer (score 16):

For the latest MUI v5.2.2:
There are two main ways of changing TextField color properties:

1st one is by using InputProps and InputLabelProps:
First you can create a some.module.css file, where you can create your classes:

```
.input-border {
    border-color: #3E68A8 !important;
}

.inputLabel {
    color: #3E68A8 !important;
}

.helper-text {
    text-transform: initial;
    font-size: 1rem !important;
}
```

after that you can apply them like:

```
            <TextField
              sx={{
                textTransform: 'uppercase',
              }}
              FormHelperTextProps={{
                classes: {
                  root: classes['helper-text'],
                },
              }}
              InputProps={{
                classes: {
                  notchedOutline: classes['input-border'],
                },
              }}
              InputLabelProps={{
                classes: {
                  root: classes.inputLabel,
                  focused: classes.inputLabel,
                },
              }}
            />
```

Note the above shows also how to change the color of the FormHelperText!

But if you have multiple input fields, the best way is to override the components that you need by using `createTheme` from `@mui/material/styles`

The below example shows some of the components, the rest you can just check in the dev tools, and later on inside the theme file just Ctrl + Space will show you all available components.
Example:

```
import { createTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // CTRL + SPACE to find the component you would like to override.
    // For most of them you will need to adjust just the root...
    MuiTextField: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          '& label': {
            color: '#3E68A8',
          },
          '& label.Mui-focused': {
            color: '#3E68A8',
          },
          '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
            borderBottomColor: '#3E68A8',
          },
          '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
            '& fieldset': {
              borderColor: '#3E68A8',
            },
            '&:hover fieldset': {
              borderColor: '#3E68A8',
              borderWidth: '0.15rem',
            },
            '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
              borderColor: '#3E68A8',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    MuiFormHelperText: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          textTransform: 'initial',
          fontSize: '1rem',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default responsiveFontSizes(theme);
```

Comment: still feeling out the ```createTheme()``` syntax. this was a perfect example of the 5.x version syntax to get me where i needed to be. much thanks! +1

Comment: much thanks for the answer, but can you share the references where I can find the name of the classes? like `.MuiOutlinedInput-root . & fieldset ` where can I find those name?

Answer (score 9):

use this overriding CSS property

```
.MuiFormLabel-root.Mui-focused {
  color: red !important;
}
.MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

But in general, if you want to customize MUI components based on your design system, you have to follow MUI infrastructure [here v4](https://v4.mui.com/customization/components/)

Answer (score 8):

```
  inputProps={{ style: { fontFamily: 'nunito', color: 'white'}}}
```

The Inputprops works by styling the enterd input data in the textfield and also we can use className for custom coloring..

```
      const CssTextField = withStyles({
     root: {
    '& label.Mui-focused': {
     color: 'white',
      },
     '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
      borderBottomColor: 'yellow',
     },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
     '& fieldset': {
     borderColor: 'white',
     },
     '&:hover fieldset': {
      borderColor: 'white',
       },
     '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
       borderColor: 'yellow',
     },
     },
    },
```

This const style works the outer potion of the text filed...

The styling of the outer portion of material UI is above asked for change...

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I did it for hover and focused states of the TextField component.

```
MuiTextField: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
        borderColor: "#ffb535",
      },
      "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused  .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline":
        {
          borderColor: "#ffb535",
        },
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: How about label color?

Answer (score 4):

Extending Peter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53336479/2088134). You could also change all event colors without the `!important`:

```
 cssOutlinedInput: {
        "&:not(hover):not($disabled):not($cssFocused):not($error) $notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: "red" //default      
        },
        "&:hover:not($disabled):not($cssFocused):not($error) $notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: "blue" //hovered
        },
        "&$cssFocused $notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: "purple" //focused
        }
      },
      notchedOutline: {},
      cssFocused: {},
      error: {},
      disabled: {}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-ui-custom-outline-color-c6zqxp

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved mine.

I wanted to change the color of the TextField when on foucused. As you already know, material Ui textField default color when on focused is blue. Blue the primary color.

So here was the hack, I went to the outer component App, and then defined a function called createMuiTheme. This fuctions returns an object called pallete. Inside the pallete is where you provide your color overides. You will use ThemeProvider from materia ui to apply your new defined color theme to your app just as below. For more clarification, follow this link https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/

```
import {createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider} from '@material-ui/core';
import FormInput from './FormInput';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "your own color", //this overide blue color
      light: "your own color", //overides light blue
      dark: "your own color", //overides dark blue color
    },
  },
});


//apply your new color theme to your app component
function App(){
return(
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}> //applies custom theme
   <FormInput/>
</ThemeProvider>
)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can override this style like below

```
/* for change border color*/
.MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline{
    border-color: #5EA841 !important;
}

/*for change label color in focus state*/
.MuiFormLabel-root.Mui-focused{
    color: #212121 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> The overrides key enables you to customize the appearance of all instances of a component type,... [Material-Ui](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/)

In this case there is a short answer, you have to use ThemeProvider and createMuiTheme

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  createMuiTheme,
  ThemeProvider
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#ff5722' //your color
    }
  }
});

function CustomTextfield(props) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <TextField variant='outlined'/>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

For a more complete customization you can use the default theme names [pallete](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/). 
If you dont know where are the names or naming conventions.
Using de browser inspector in the style section is your savior, you can notice how the css chain is made in material-ui.

```
.MuiFilledInput-root {
position: relative;
transition: background-color 200ms cubic-bezier(0.0, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
border-top-left-radius: 4px;
border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

MuiFilledInput > root > background-color:

we have to create de theme using the data from the inspector, we only have to place the chain in overrides:{}

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiFilledInput: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)',
        '&:hover': {
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'
        },
        '&.Mui-focused': {
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Now you can make the override using ThemeProvider

```
import {
  createMuiTheme,
  ThemeProvider
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiFilledInput: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)',
        '&:hover': {
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'
        },
        '&.Mui-focused': {
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

function CustomTextfield(props) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <TextField variant='filled' />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

So for this question you have to search your own components, because have different names.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code to customize its border color using `styled()` in **MUI v5**. The resulted `TextField` has an extra `borderColor` prop that lets you pass any color you want, not just the ones from MUI palette.

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import MuiTextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

const options = {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'borderColor',
};
const outlinedSelectors = [
  '& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline',
  '&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline',
  '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline',
];
const TextField = styled(
  MuiTextField,
  options,
)(({ borderColor }) => ({
  '& label.Mui-focused': {
    color: borderColor,
  },
  [outlinedSelectors.join(',')]: {
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor,
  },
}));
```

#### Usage

```
<TextField label="green" borderColor="green" />
<TextField label="red" borderColor="red" />
<TextField label="blue" borderColor="blue" />
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 2):

For me, the easiest way to do it.

```
<TextField
    size="small"
    className="footerFormInput"
    label="Name"
    fullWidth
    sx={{
      "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
        "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
          borderColor: "orange",
        },
      },
   }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can refer this code:

styles.js

```
cssLabel: {
  color : 'rgb(61, 158, 116) !important'
}, 
notchedOutline: {
  borderWidth: '1px',
  borderColor: 'rgb(61, 158, 116) !important',
  color: 'rgb(61, 158, 116)',
},
```

form.js

```
<TextField
                name="creator"
                focused="true" 
                variant="outlined" 
                label="Creator"  
                fullwidth
                InputLabelProps={{
                    classes: {
                      root: classes.cssLabel,
                      focused: classes.cssLabel,
                    },
                }}
                InputProps={{
                    classes: {
                      root: classes.notchedOutline,
                      focused: classes.notchedOutline,
                      notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
                    },
                    
                 }}
               
 />
```

basically, you need to set border color of notchedOutline of the InputProps appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

In MUI V5 :

```
const theme = createTheme({
    
     components: {
        MuiInputBase: {
          styleOverrides: {
            root: {
              "&:before":{
                borderBottom:"1px solid yellow !imporatnt",}
            },
          },
        },
      },
    
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

In MUI V5, the best way to handle the styles is through the SX props, as shown in the following example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

// 1- Default styles
const rootStyles = {
  backgroundColor: '#ffd60a',
  border: '3px solid #001d3d',
};

const inputLabelStyles = {
  color: '#003566',
  textTransform: 'capitalize',
};

const rootInputStyles = {
  '&:hover fieldset': {
    border: '2px solid blue!important',
    borderRadius: 0,
  },
  '&:focus-within fieldset, &:focus-visible fieldset': {
    border: '4px solid red!important',
  },
};

const inputStyles = {
  color: 'red',
  paddingLeft: '15px',
  fontSize: '20px',
};

const helperTextStyles = {
  color: 'red',
};

export default function InputField({
  label = 'default label',
  // 2- User custom styles
  customRootStyles,
  customInputLabelStyles,
  customRootInputStyles,
  customInputStyles,
  customHelperTextStyles,
}) {
  return (
    <TextField
      label={label}
      helperText="Please enter a valid input"
      sx={{ ...rootStyles, ...customRootStyles }}
      InputLabelProps={{
        sx: {
          ...inputLabelStyles,
          ...customInputLabelStyles,
        },
      }}
      InputProps={{
        sx: {
          ...rootInputStyles,
          ...customRootInputStyles,
        },
      }}
      inputProps={{
        sx: {
          ...inputStyles,
          ...customInputStyles,
        },
      }}
      FormHelperTextProps={{
        sx: {
          ...helperTextStyles,
          ...customHelperTextStyles,
        },
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

To understand more about how this works, you can checkout the original article through this [link](https://www.js-howto.com/how-to-change-the-styles-of-mui-textfield-in-react/).

Answer (score 1):

```
With this code I can change the border colors during hover and focus
```

```
    const MyApp = () => {
        const theme = createTheme({
                        palette: {
                            primary: {
                                main: '#777777',
                                borderWidth: "1px !important"
                            },
                        },
                        overrides: {
                            MuiOutlinedInput: {
                                root: {
                                    '&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error) $notchedOutline': {
                                        borderColor: 'red',
                                    },
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    });
            
          return (  
     
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>    
    
                      <Autocomplete
                        multiple
                        options={categoryTypes}
                        disableCloseOnSelect
                        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.value}
                        renderOption={(option, {selected}) => (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <Checkbox style={{marginRight: 8, padding: 0}} checked={selected}/>
                                {option.name}
                            </React.Fragment>
                        )}
                        onChange={(e, item, eventName, currentItem) => handleCheck(e, item, eventName, currentItem, 'categories')}
                        style={{marginRight: 80}}
                        renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField  {...params} variant="outlined" label="Choose a categories" placeholder="Favorites"/>
                        )}
                    />
    
           </ThemeProvider>
        )
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problem with all these complex solutions so I found easy one.

```
import { TextField, styled } from "@mui/material";

export const TextFieldStyled = styled(TextField)(
    ({ theme }) => `
        
        p {
            color: white;
        }

        .MuiInputBase-input {
            color: white;
        }

        label {
            color: white;
        }

        .Mui-focused {
            color: orange !important;
            border-color: orange !important;
        }

        fieldset {
            border-color: white;
        }

        .Mui-focused fieldset {
            border-color: orange !important;
        }

        svg {
            color: white;
        }

        &:hover {
            fieldset {
                border-color: orange !important;
            }
        }
    `
)
```

Instead of elements, you can reference classes without generated part you can find in Inspect Element.

When defined style, just use it instead of component

```
Instead of this:
<TextField />

use this:
<TextFieldStyled  />
```

This one work with combobox too

Answer (score 0):

Here this example on a select input:

```
import {
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  Select,
  MenuItem,
  OutlinedInput as MuiOutlinedInput,
} from "@material-ui/core";
    
const OutlinedInput = withStyles((theme) => ({
  notchedOutline: {
    borderColor: "white !important",
  },
}))(MuiOutlinedInput);

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  select: {
    color: "white",
  },
  icon: { color: "white" },
  label: { color: "white" },
}));

function Component() {
  return (
    <FormControl variant="outlined">
      <InputLabel id="labelId" className={classes.label}>
        Label
      </InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="labelId"
        classes={{
          select: classes.select,
          icon: classes.icon,
        }}
        input={<OutlinedInput label="Label" />}
      >
        <MenuItem>A</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>B</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to use pure css with this:

```js
.mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-floating-label {
  color: #cfd8dc !important;
}
.mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-notched-outline__leading,
.mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-notched-outline__notch,
.mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-color: #cfd8dc !important;
}

// optional caret color
.mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-text-field__input {
  caret-color: #cfd8dc !important;
}
```

J

Answer (score 0):

Styled the component Mui TextField with a special selector ".MuiInputBase-root:hover:not(.Mui-disabled, .Mui-error):before"

```js
export const FormTextArea = styled(TextField)(({ theme }) => ({
  marginBottom: "5px",
  letterSpacing: useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("cm")) ? "3px" : "0",
  "& .MuiFormLabel-root": {
    fontFamily: "Commuters Sans Extra",
    fontWeight: "200",
    fontStyle: "italic",
    fontSize: "12px",
  },
  "& .MuiInputBase-root:hover:not(.Mui-disabled, .Mui-error):before": {
    borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.secondary.main}`,
  },
}));
```

when hover, the color changes[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvu8M.jpg)