# Material UI v5 global override input border

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How would I override the border colour when focused for all MUI inputs for outlined variants in MUI v5?
I want to use `createTheme` to override this rule:

> .css-1ky26vl-MuiInputBase-root-MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52911169/how-to-change-the-border-color-of-mui-textfield

Comment: no it doesn't. The solution is for an older version of MUI (not v5) and doesn't use createTheme