# MUI V5 Textfield - Change border color?

Tags: material-ui

using Material UI V5 and i can't change the border color of my TextField with the `sx` prop.

Changing the color of the label and input works fine, but not with border color.

```
<TextField
        sx={{ 
          input: { color: 'white' } ,
          label: {color: 'white'},
          borderColor: 'white',
          border: {color: 'white'},
        }}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the border should be visible only for outlined TextFields. Is that correct?
Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52911169/how-to-change-the-border-color-of-mui-textfield

Answer (score 6):

The TextField is a weird one, the border is actually defined on the fieldset element. The following should style that.

```
<TextField 
  sx={{
    fieldset: { borderColor: "red" }
  }}
```

Here is a screen capture of the TextField HTML to help show the fieldset element I'm talking about.
[image]

Comment: But I need to add the color only  when the input is active

Comment: I'm guessing the following would work? sx={{ "&:active fieldset": { borderColor: "red"} }}
I do not have anything in front of me to verify that snippet to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

For changing the border color, you can change borderBottom color inside input:

```
 <TextField sx={{
                input: {
                       color: "#ffffff",
                       borderBottom: "1px solid #ffffff",
                       },
                 }}/>
```